# Issue with complex value in EQ Solver String return

Tags: java, android, equation

I have this method to solve quadratic equation that returns 2 types of array according the delta (if less than zero than there are complex solutions)

```
public static final String[] quadEquationSolver(double a, double b, double c) {
        double delta = (b * b) - 4 * a * c;
        double q;
        if (delta < 0) {
            double deltar = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(delta));
            q = ((b < 0) ? -0.5 * (b - deltar) : -0.5 * (b + deltar));
            double t0 = q / a;
            double t1 = c / q;
            // return sorted array
            return (t0 > t1) ? new String[] { t1 + "i", t0 + "i" }
                    : new String[] { t0 + "i", t1 + "i" };
        } else {
            double deltar = Math.sqrt(delta);
            q = ((b < 0) ? -0.5 * (b - deltar) : -0.5 * (b + deltar));
            double t0 = q / a;
            double t1 = c / q;
            // return sorted array
            return (t0 > t1) ? new String[] { t1 + "", t0 + "" }
                    : new String[] { t0 + "", t1 + "" };
        }

    }
```

unfortunately when `delta<0` i get a String array that contains only `NaNi` values despite the right result, but I cannot figure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
if (delta < 0) {
            double deltar = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(delta));
```

When `delta < 0`,  `Math.sqrt(delta)` will return `NaN` and  `Math.abs(NaN)` will also return NaN according to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) . Any subsequent formulas involving NaN values will produce NaN results aswell, hence why you are seeing the result you are seeing.

You should try swapping the `Math.sqrt` and `Math.abs` method call, to avoid this issue like so:

```
if (delta < 0) {
            double deltar = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(delta));
```

The Java Math library doesn't support complex number processing as such. If you want to utilize complex numbers explicitly, you could try looking at the [Apache Commons Math Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html)

Comment: I'm wondering how I didn't noticed this big mistake... thanks!